# what has replaced dconf-tools for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, restart, dconf

This strikes me as a bit chaotic, but I'm new to Ubuntu. I want to have the option to restore open apps when I shut down or logout of Ubuntu 20.04. As usual, I did a search, and found two articles that said basically the same thing: "use `dconf-tools` for this" ([HTG article](https://www.howtogeek.com/203952/how-to-automatically-remember-running-applications-from-your-last-session-in-ubuntu-14.04/), [LinOxide article](https://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/remember-running-applications-ubuntu/)).

Attempting to install this tool with `apt`, I learn that the `dconf-tools` package is not available. OK - so something's there to replace it - right? ["Maybe not" is the answer here;](https://askubuntu.com/a/1084504/831935) the author of that answer indicates it "never worked well"? It was also suggested that `Window Session Manager` was good & well-maintained... but then he also said the entire concept never worked well?! [Another Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/1152548/831935) suggested that `dconf-tools` had a replacement in `dconf-cli` - except that was for use as a dependency in another package, so...?

Also - quick search through the `Ubuntu Software` app shows there is an app called `Dconf Editor`, but its description is so terse as to be useless.

Since I've not seen anything for 20.04, I thought it was worth asking the question again: How to restore open windows and apps from my last session? Or, what has replaced `dconf-tools`?

Comment: There's no auto-save-session in Ubuntu 20.04 . You have to use the [Window session manager extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1323/window-session-manager/). And also there's no need to use Dconf editor for it anymore.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Dies Link does not work anymore. I found [Another Window Session Manager](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4709/another-window-session-manager/). Might be similar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The package `dconf-tools` was most recently a transitional package which had the dependencies `dconf-cli` and `dconf-editor` so all you have to do is install those two packages:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dconf-cli dconf-editor
```

as `dconf-editor` is the one referred to in the HTG article.

Additionally, it's provided by the Universe repository which is supposed to be enabled by default but just in case I added an extra command to ensure this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd like to try this, but given its history I'm not sure it's as *reliable* as I'd like. Can you tell me if you use this on your system & if so, does it seem reliable to you?

Comment: Yes, it's reliable as a replacement for dconf-tools and I use it but I don't use it for session saving. I can say that the author of the HTG article called for installing dconf-tools as a means to install dconf-editor. Also, it depends on what you use it for. The reliability answer you referenced talks about the hibernation feature and I'm pretty sure this session saving feature is different (I'm guessing more like session saving used on XFCE4 desktop) and they dropped support in 2011 (old Gnome desktop) and the HTG article was written in 2014 for Gnome Shell.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `org.gnome.gnome-session` config option anymore.You have to install the extension [Window Session Manager](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1323/window-session-manager/).

> An indicator that let's you save and restore your open apps and the window positions and arrangements over multiple real and virtual displays. Requires lwsm and nodejs to be installed (`npm install -g linux-window-session-manager`).